# Combine org nodes in separate files into a single tree recursively

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I want to compose "recipes," consisting of "subroutines" defined as org nodes in separate files, into a single tree.

I can't get the behavior I want because (it seems) the org exporter handles `#+INCLUDE`s iteratively.

The level of each node relative to the absolute root is not known a priori.

root.org:

```
* root
#+INCLUDE: sub.org :minlevel 2
#+INCLUDE: sub.org :minlevel 2
```

sub.org:

```
* sub
#+INCLUDE: subsub.org :minlevel 2
#+INCLUDE: subsub.org :minlevel 2
```

subsub.org:

```
* subsub
```

When I export to org (`C-c C-e O O`) I get:

```
* root
** sub
** subsub
** subsub
** sub
** subsub
** subsub
```

If I remove all `:minlevel 2` I get:

```
* root
** sub
*** subsub
**** subsub
***** sub
****** subsub
******* subsub
```

What I want is:

```
* root
** sub
*** subsub
*** subsub
** sub
*** subsub
*** subsub
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Make `:minlevel 3` in `sub.org`?

Comment: @NickD The level of each node is only known relative to the headline in its own file. I want to be able to reuse sub.org in another recipe at any level.

Comment: So why specify `:minlevel` at all?

Comment: @NickD The question shows the output when `:minlevel` is not included and how it differs from the output I'm after.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. What version of Org mode are you using?

Comment: org-version 8.2.10 on GNU emacs 25.2.2 on Ubuntu 18 LTS

Comment: You might want to upgrade: I'm running org 9.4 and the "no minlevel" output I get is exactly what you want. 8.2.10 is six years old and  a *lot* has happened to Org mode since then.

Comment: Ah yes, installing the latest org gives me what I would have expected.  I didn't realize I was using the bundled version.  Thanks!